# Redirect example.com to www.example.com

Tags: dns

I have the following.
what should I add to make example.com be redirected to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)?

```
Name    TTL Type    Address
example.com 14400   A   153.92.211.25
www.example.com 14400   A   153.92.211.25
www.example.com 14400   CNAME    example.com
```

Comment: nothing - this redirection should happen on your web server, not within the DNS.   Also, this is off topic here.   SO is for questions about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

A CNAME record is as close as you can get, but that only causes `example.com` to resolve to the same address as `www.example.com`.

This is great for when you have multiple hostnames that need to resolve to the same server as, if you ever change the IP address of that server, you only have to update one record.

(Note that a CNAME record can't be applied to the root of the domain. You can use CNAME to say that `www.example.com` or `cdn.example.com` resolve to `example.com` but not the reverse).

It won't cause the client to redirect though. It will ask for `example.com` and be told `153.92.211.25`, not "You should go to `www.example.com` instead.

For a redirect you need to use an HTTP redirect. Generally this will be a `301 Moved Permanently` status and a `Location` header with the new URL (`https://www.example.com`) as the value.